# What is the explanation of the phrase “as was supposed” in Luke 3:23 and how it appears in original text?

Tags: luke, christology, terminology

Luke 3:23: “Now Jesus Himself began His ministry at about thirty years of age, being (as was supposed) ...” (NKJV)

Comment: It's not in the Codex Syriac Synaticus which represents a very early version of the gospels.

Answer (score 2):

Berean Study Bible

> Jesus Himself was about thirty years old when He began His ministry. **He was regarded as the son of Joseph**, the son of Heli,

In the original Greek, it is just a word. It carries a sense of being generally accepted fact that Jesus was the son of Joseph, in the indicative mood.

known, supposed
ἐνομίζετο (enomizeto)
Verb - Imperfect Indicative Middle or Passive - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's Greek 3543: From nomos; properly, to do by law, i.e. To accustom; by extension, to deem or regard.

Strong's Concordance

> Definition: to practice, consider
> Usage: I practice, hold by custom; I deem, think, consider, suppose.

Thayer's Greek Lexicon

> 1. to hold by custom or usage, own as a custom or usage; to follow custom or usage; **passive** νομίζεται it is the custom, it is the received usage: οὗ ἐνομίζετο προσευχή εἶναι, where **according to custom** was a place of prayer
> 2. to deem, think, suppose: followed by an infinitive, Acts 8:20; 1 Corinthians 7:36; followed by an accusative with an infinitive, Luke 2:44; Acts 7:25; Acts 14:19; Acts 16:(18 (see 1 above)), Acts 16:27; Acts 17:29; 1 Corinthians 7:26; 1 Timothy 6:5; followed by ὅτι, Matthew 5:17; Matthew 10:34 (Winer's Grammar, § 56, 1 b.); Matthew 20:10; Acts 21:29; ὡς ἐνομίζετο, **as was accustomed to be supposed**, Luke 3:23. (Synonym: see ἡγέομαι, at the end.)

Luke used this Greek word to hint that Joseph was not the biological father but a legal one.

Barnes' Notes on the Bible

> As was supposed - As was commonly thought, or perhaps being **legally** reckoned as his son.

John 6:42 confirms this common knowledge:

> They said, "Is this not Jesus, the son of Joseph, whose father and mother we know? How can he now say, 'I came down from heaven'?"

Comment: Very good and complete answer. +1